# Mock factory on controller test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, controller, factory

this is **my controller**:

```
angular
.module('studentsApp')
.controller('StudentsController', StudentsController);

function StudentsController($scope, StudentsFactory) {
    $scope.students = [];
    $scope.specificStudent= {};

    var getStudents = function() {
        StudentsFactory.getStudents().then(function(response) {
            if($scope.students.length > 0){
                $scope.students = [];
            }
            $scope.students.push(response.data);
        });
    };
}
```

This is **my factory**:

```
angular.module('studentsApp')
.factory('StudentsFactory', function($http) {
  var base_url = 'http://localhost:3000';
  var studentsURI = '/students';
  var studentURI = '/student';
  var config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  };

  return {
    getStudents: function() {
      return $http.get(base_url + studentsURI);
    }
  };
});
```

And here is how **I'm trying to unit test the controller**:

```
describe('Controller: Students', function() {
  var StudentsController, scope, StudentsFactory;
  beforeEach(function() {
    module('studentsApp');
    inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $httpBackend, $injector) {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
      StudentsFactory = $injector.get('StudentsFactory');

      StudentsController = $controller('StudentsController', {
        $scope : scope,
        'StudentsFactory' : StudentsFactory
      });

      students = [{
        name: 'Pedro',
        age: 10
      }, {
        name: 'João',
        age: 11
      }, {
        name: 'Thiago',
        age: 9
      }];

      spyOn(StudentsFactory, 'getStudents').and.returnValue(students);
    });
  });

  it('Should get all students', function() {
    scope.students = [];

    StudentsController.getStudents();
    $scope.$apply();
    expect(scope.students.length).toBe(3);
  });
});
```

**The problem is** when I run the test, the following message is displayed:

> undefined is not a constructor (evaluating
>   'StudentsController.getStudents()')

I looked at the whole internet trying to find a tutorial that can help me on that, but I didn't find anything, could someone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

It's link to the fact that the function getStudent() is private (declared by var). Thus your test can't access it. You have to attach it to the $scope or this to be able to test it.
I generally use this in controller:

```
var $this = this;
$this.getStudents = function() {
    ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Gerald, I made as you mentioned, now, I'm having problem on test with the following message: **undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'StudentsFactory.getStudents().then')** how can I proceed with that?

Comment: I will do this : http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/07/13/unit-test-promises-angualrjs-q/

Answer (score 0):

There's no `StudentsController.getStudents` method. It should be

```
this.getStudents = function () { ... };
```

Mocked `StudentsFactory.getStudents` returns a plain object, while it is expected to return a promise.

`$controller` shouldn't be provided with real `StudentsFactory` service as local dependency (it is already provided with it by default):

```
  var mockedStudentsFactory = {
    getStudents: jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue($q.resolve(students))
  };

  StudentsController = $controller('StudentsController', {
    $scope : scope,
    StudentsFactory : mockedStudentsFactory
  });
```

Comment: I tried that, but, it's not adding the value of students to the scope.students.. Another thing is. i'm not using $q, I'm using $http, it is a problem?

Comment: $http returns $q promise, the response may be mocked with settled $q promise. `students` is an array in your case, it is expected to be an object with `data` property. At this point it should either work or throw a meaningful error. If this still doesn't work for you, please, post a fiddle/plunk that could show what's going wrong in your case.

Comment: thanks, but is not working yet, it looks that is calling the promise, but is not put the value of array inside the scope.students, I created a fiddle, so that u can see the code better: https://jsfiddle.net/z9k3c35c/ can u help me?

Comment: The fiddle you've posted isn't workable. It is not clear what's going wrong in your case, at this point it should work. A working fiddle that runs the spec and shows the error would help. Please, post the exact error that you have (with call stack) with all the corrections.